# Laravel localhost url problems

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I use Windows 10 and XAMPP for local development. I want to create project on laravel 5.5 and access it in browser by **project.dev**

I add next lines to httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost project.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp7\htdocs\server\laravel\project_name\public"
    ServerAdmin project.dev
    <Directory "C:\xampp7\htdocs\server\laravel\project_name">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
127.0.0.1       project.dev
```

to hosts file. But it does not work (only for laravel),I get 400 error.
This works with all the rest my local projects except those ones on laravel.

I have no problem with access to this project by

```
http://localhost/server/laravel/project_name/public
```

What other settings do I have to make to access laravel 5.5 project like project.dev?

Answer (score 2):

1- change **VirtualHost project.dev:80** to **VirtualHost *:80** 
2- change **ServerAdmin project.dev** to **ServerName project.dev**
and after these changes restart your apache service

Comment: unfortunatelly it didn't work. I still get the same 400 error and now I can't access it even with http://localhost/server/laravel/project_name/public

Comment: Is this the very first virtual-host you created? Because if you use virtual-hosts thrn you have to create a virtual host for localhost as well. Otherwise calling localhost will not work. Also did you try putting `public` in the Directory-path as well?